# SQL performance like and UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables OSD_SPLIT which contains are 180K records with words to be flagged and TRANSPLIT which has the sentence split up on spaces e.g. sentence My name is XYZ so TRANSPLIT would have 4 rows My, name, is, XYZ.

I have 2 sqls one to match 1 letter distance e.g. TRANSPLIT has a row SHARK and OSD_SPLIT has word SHRAK I would like it to match i.e. edit_distance is 1 and lengths are same.

The other SQL is to look for OSD_SPLIT words inline within TRANSPLIT e.g. TRANSPLIT has XSHARKX I would like it to match with SHARK because SHARK exists inline within XSHARKX

Below are the 2 SQLs and I would like to improve performance both the SQLs are doing full table scans on OSD_SPLIT table I guess because I am using edit_distance and like '%%' any suggestions on improving performance

```
SELECT DISTINCT OS.STOP_DSC
    FROM OSD_SPLIT OS, TRANSPLIT TS
    WHERE TS.TXTSPLIT1 <> OS.STOP_DSC
    AND TS.ORGTXT = TS.TXTSPLIT1
    AND LENGTH(TS.TXTSPLIT1) > 1
    AND LENGTH(TS.TXTSPLIT1) = LENGTH(OS.STOP_DSC)
    AND UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(TS.TXTSPLIT1, OS.STOP_DSC) = 1

SELECT DISTINCT OS.STOP_DSC
        FROM OSD_SPLIT OS, TRANSPLIT TS
        WHERE TS.TXTSPLIT1 <> OS.STOP_DSC 
        AND TS.TXTSPLIT1 LIKE '%'||OS.STOP_DSC||'%'
        AND LENGTH(TS.TXTSPLIT1) >= LENGTH(OS.STOP_DSC)
        AND LENGTH(TS.TXTSPLIT1) >= 3 AND LENGTH(OS.STOP_DSC) >= 3 
        AND ((LENGTH(TS.TXTSPLIT1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TS.TXTSPLIT1,OS.STOP_DSC,'')))/LENGTH(TS.TXTSPLIT1))*100 >= 80
```

Comment: 180K is a pretty small table, and a modern database with good CPU should be able to do full table scans on that very quickly. If you are applying functions to determine which rows to include, you almost always will need a full table scan, though there is some room for tuning. What is the performance you are experiencing (how long to run the query), and what is your target?

Comment: Totally agree, the time also depends on the data as well that comes in TRANSPLIT if it is a long or short sentence but an average the edit_distance SQL is take 2-3 seconds to execute any suggestions on improvement? Trying to bring time down as much as possible i can see that oracle needs to do a full scan and try to compute edit_distance with each and every record in OSD_SPLIT of same length

Comment: The EDIT_DISTANCE is taking 2-3 seconds and the inline text matching sql is taking around 1.5 seconds so total time it is taking is 4-5 seconds and I would like to bring it down as much as possible.

Comment: Your best bet is to find out how to filter down the domain of stuff to check, with some kind of WHERE clause. Oracle has no choice but to evaluate `EDIT_DISTANCE` for every possible pairing, so a full table scan is being done. It's likely that you are using CPU for most of the time, because of the functions. Perhaps this is an appropriate place for parallel query (usually more trouble than it's worth) since Oracle could do this in multiple threads.

Comment: Try adding `/*+ PARALLEL(8) */` or a similar hint right after the `SELECT` keyword. No guarantees that Oracle will be smart enough to break up your job into bits, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @TadHarrison never mind i did google on it and it is interesting, thanks a lot it has for sure shaved off like a second or so, I am trying to determine degree of parallelism.